# How do I convert int into char[] to display time?

Tags: java, swing, converters

I've written a simulation and would like to display the time in the `JFrame` along with the animation. 
I am calling my animation by overriding the `paintComponent` method and repainting every timestep.
 However, my time counter is in `(int)seconds`, and the only method I know to write text is `g.drawChars`, which requires an array of chars.

Any idea on how I can convert my time in seconds to char array so I can display time in a human-readable way?

Comment: You can cast it to string and use drawString method.

Comment: What about `g.drawString`? Use it with `String.valueOf(yourInteger)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `yourIntValue` represents your seconds.

`new Integer(yourIntValue).toString().toCharArray()` should do the trick.

The easier way is using `String.valueOf(yourIntValue).toCharArray()`

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a `char[]` <sup>1</sup>

So you can just convert your `int` to `String` and then return the `char[]`

```
String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Elaborating a bit on that statement.
If you look at the `String` class you will see that it implements `CharSequence`
It also declares, and adds the javadoc comment

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];
```

For brevity I will also just post the default constructor for `String`

```
public String() {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = 0;
    this.value = new char[0];
}
```

You can have a look at the other constructors to see how it builds the `char[]` for every `String`.

---

***Edit:***
I wanted to comment on one of the other answers, but I have not enough rep, so I will post it as part of my answer.

```
String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
```

and

```
Integer.toString(i).toCharArray();
```

is the (almost) same call. This is because the `valueOf(int i)` method of `String` is:

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert first to String and then convert to char array.

```
     int time = 10;
     char[] chars = Integer.toString(time).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
int minutes = seconds / 60;
int remainingSeconds = seconds - (minutes * 60); // or int remainingSeconds = seconds % 60
String time = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
char[] timeCharArray = time.toCharArray();
```

Also see the [documentation of `toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

Comment: You can just do `seconds %= 60;`

Comment: @TimB double naming the variable `seconds` was unitentional ;-) Besides that, modulo would of course also work. I'm just not a friend of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the time formatted or just displayed as a second count?

As a second count do:

```
String.valueOf(yourInt).toCharArray();
```

To format it do:

```
String time = (yourInt/(60*60))+":"+((yourInt/60)%60)+":"+(yourInt%60);
time.toCharArray();
```

But the graphics objects have a drawString() option which will allow you to skip the toCharArray() step anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Convert time from int to Date (miliseconds is the int you have, just transform it from seconds to miliseconds):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Parse the date to local format and you get a string (example of format is "dd.MM.yyyy"):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String humanReadableDate = sdf.format(date);
```